# Python Socket invalid Argument

Tags: python, windows, sockets, networking, hackintosh

Some util informations:
OS: Windows 10 (with WSL2 installed)
IDE: Emacs

I'm working in a project using the python socket library.

I made a class to organize the server processes, inside that server I have the method "requestConnection", when I call the method it gives me an error "Errno 22 [invalid argument]".

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SocketChat.py", line 4, in <module>
    servidor.requestConnection()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/Mauro/Development/Projects/SocketChat/server.py", line 16, in requestConnection
    self.con = self.server_socket.accept()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 292, in accept
    fd, addr = self._accept()
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Here's the main code:

```
from server import Server, Chat

servidor = Server('127.0.0.1', '5000')
servidor.requestConnection()

chat = Chat(servidor.receiveMsg())
```

Here's the classes:

```
import socket

class Server:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.addr = (host, port)
        self.server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


    def shutDown(self):
        self.server_socket.close()


    def requestConnection(self):
        self.con = self.server_socket.accept()


    def receiveMsg(self):
        receive = self.con.recv(1024)
        return str(receive)


class Chat:
    def __init__(msg):
        self.msg = msg
        pass


    def newMsg(self):
        print(f"new message: {self.msg.decode()}")
        pass
```

If you know how to solve this problem, please give-me the answer

Comment: You shouldn’t post pictures of text: paste the important text _as text_ into your question.

Comment: @barny done thanks, do you know how to solve this btw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to pass the port number as integer, not string:

```
from server import Server, Chat

servidor = Server('127.0.0.1', 5000)
```